# Could not remove using parent div id in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I facing one issue. I need to remove total div using the id in Jquery while clicking on minus button. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php foreach($module as $item){ ?>
<div id="planWithfriends<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">PLAN WITH FRIENDS</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="row" action="" method="POST">
              <div class="input_fields_wrap<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
                <div id="parentid<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="go-right" style="margin-bottom:0px;">Email </label>
                    <input name="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="go-right" style="margin-bottom:0px;">Phone </label>
                    <input name="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="add_button_<?php echo $item->id; ?> btn btn-success" style="height:34px;margin-top: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-right">
                <button style="margin-top:25px;" type="button" class="btn btn-action" data-dismiss="modal" id="planbutton<?php echo $item->id; ?>">Submit</button>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-action" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var addButton = $('.add_button_<?php echo $item->id; ?>');
    var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap<?php echo $item->id; ?>');
    $(addButton).click(function(){
      $(wrapper).append('<div id="parentid<?php echo $item->id; ?>"><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input name="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;"></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input name="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;"></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><button type="button" class="remove_field<?php echo $item->id; ?> btn btn-danger" style="height:34px;margin-top: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div></div>'); //

    })
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field<?php echo $item->id; ?>', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('#parentid<?php echo $item->id; ?>').remove();
    })
  })
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Here I creating another row clicking on `+` button but when user will click on `-` button the respective row should remove which is not happening in my case. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Never ever put javascript/jquery code inside PHP loops. Whats the point of repeating the code again and again?

Answer (score 1):

As I have seen you put JavaScript code inside the loop. Please put it outside the loop as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap');
    $(addButton).click(function(){
      $(wrapper).append('<div id="parentid"><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input name="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="email_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;"></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input name="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>[]" id="phone_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control input_style1" placeholder="" value="" style="height:34px;"></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><button type="button" class="remove_field<?php echo $item->id; ?> btn btn-danger" style="height:34px;margin-top: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div></div>'); //

    })
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('.parentid').remove();
    })
  })
</script>
```

and give a class `remove_field` when clicking on it get `parent div class` and do whatever you want. This is not good practicing to put JavaScript inside the PHP loop.